# Formatting Java Logging

Tags: java, logging, formatter

I am trying to format some java logging through a properties file, however it is not working.
I have these lines in the properties file:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=mypackage.logging.LogFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=mypackage.logging.LogFormatter
```

where my custom formatter LogFormatter is in mypackage.logging

The log output is showing that the SimpleFormatter is being used, rather than my custom formatter.

How can I get my custom formatter to be used through the logging properties file?

edit:
I have tried all the premade formatters such as com.bea.logging.LogMessageFormatter, SimpleFormatter and XmlFormatter.  They work just fine.  It's just any new formatter that I create does not work (extending Formatter).  Could this be a classpath issue?

Answer (score 1):

The LogManager will report errors to System.err which is probably redirected to a log file.  Finding that log file should help you out.

If you are dealing with any class not visible from [system class loader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader%28%29) you'll run into [JDK-6448699 LogManager does not load log handler correctly](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6448699) and [JDK-6878454 LogManager class loading inconsistent with Java EE best practices](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6878454).

To prove your Formatter is visible from the system class path try the following code:

```
Class.forName("mypackage.logging.LogFormatter", true, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

You can set the `sun.misc.URLClassPath.debug` system property to `true` or use the `-verbose:class` on launch to get some more debug information on classloading.